# how to change all POSIXt to character throughout a list of df

Tags: r

I know for a df, I can do `df<-df %>% modify_if(is.POSIXt, as.character)`. If I have a list of df `lst`, how can I do this through every df in `lst`? I know I probably need to use `map` or `lapply`, but I am not sure how. Could someone give me some guidance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a `list` of datasets and wanted to change the column type and return the same data.frame format

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
map(lst, ~ .x %>%
             mutate(across(where(is.POSIXt), as.character)))
```

Or with `inherits`

```
map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
              mutate(across(where(~ inherits(., 'POSIXct')), as.character )))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track:

```r
new.lst <- lapply( lst, \(x) x %>% modify_if( is.POSIXt, as.character) )
```

For *ancient* versions of R:

```r
new.lst <- lst %>% map( ~ .x %>% modify_if( is.POSIXt, as.character) )
```

Or lapply with function(x):

```r
new.lst <- lapply( lst, function(x) x %>% modify_if( is.POSIXt, as.character) )
```

### With minimal data to demonstrate:

```r
library(lubridate)
lst <- list( data.frame(x=now(),y=1), data.frame(z=now()-days(2),t=3) )

lst[[1]]$x

new.lst <- lapply( lst, \(x) x %>% modify_if( is.POSIXt, as.character) )

new.lst[[1]]$x
```

Output:

```
> lst[[1]]$x
[1] "2021-05-20 00:48:34 CEST"

> new.lst[[1]]$x
[1] "2021-05-20 00:48:34"
```

(the *CEST* part shows that the first output is a date)

Comment: what does `\(x) x ` do? Thanks

Comment: it's super fancy, fresh out of the oven with R 4.1.0 just a few days ago, its a one-liner function creator, `\(x) x` is the same as `function(x){ x }`

Comment: I am still on 3.6.3. So i got `Error: unexpected input in "datalist1 <- lapply( datalist1 \"`

Comment: Please make the answer suitable for R 4.0.* (and 3.6.*).